# Image in the background get cropped off when screen resolution size is less

Tags: html, css

```css
.banner-1{
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.pcontainer {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/R1tpEs7.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 32px;
  margin-top: 122px;
  padding-top: 61px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
  padding-left: 44px;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container-fluid banner-1">      
  <div class="row">        
    <div class="col">
      <div class="triangle-down"></div> 
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col offset-md-6 pcontainer">
            <h2>Why Move to Websphere Commerce v9</h2>
              <p class="one">Give customers the ability to seamlessly move between channels to browse and buy when, where and how it’s most <span><a href="#">convenient</a></span> for them. </p>
              <p class="two">IBM Watson Commerce’s innovation ecosystem offers complete and deep               <br>capabilities so you gain maximum impact from every customer interaction and transaction.</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
              Learn More
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have created a container `banner-1`. Under that I have created another container `pcontainer` with a background image of a rectangle . Now the problem which I'm facing is whenever I test in mobile/tablet, the fold in the rectangle image gets cropped off but in desktop site, its showing the full width. Is there a way to not have the cropped image in the background. I want the full image with the fold to be displayed in the background.

Comment: You can apply background-position: top right; then it will fix the image from top right corner

Comment: try giving size of image in percentage

Answer (score 1):

Try removing margin for `pcontainer`:

```css
.banner-1 {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.pcontainer {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/R1tpEs7.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 61px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
  padding-left: 44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid banner-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="triangle-down"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col offset-md-6 pcontainer">
                    <h2>Why Move to Websphere Commerce v9</h2>
                    <p class="one">Give customers the ability to seamlessly move between channels to browse and buy when, where and how it’s most <span><a href="#">convenient</a></span> for them.</p>
                    <p class="two">IBM Watson Commerce’s innovation ecosystem offers complete and deep
                        <br>capabilities so you gain maximum impact from every customer interaction and transaction.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        Learn More
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `background-position: top right;` then it will fix the image from top right corner

```css
.banner-1 {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.pcontainer {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/R1tpEs7.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 32px;
  margin-top: 122px;
  padding-top: 61px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
  padding-left: 44px;
  background-position: top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid banner-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="triangle-down"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col offset-md-6 pcontainer">
                    <h2>Why Move to Websphere Commerce v9</h2>
                    <p class="one">Give customers the ability to seamlessly move between channels to browse and buy when, where and how it’s most <span><a href="#">convenient</a></span> for them.</p>
                    <p class="two">IBM Watson Commerce’s innovation ecosystem offers complete and deep
                        <br>capabilities so you gain maximum impact from every customer interaction and transaction.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        Learn More
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```